# How to override a function in a merged namespace in typescript

Tags: typescript, namespaces

Lets say I have a namespace defined in a .d.ts file like this:

```
namespace a.b.c {
   export function hello() { console.log('hello');}
}
```

Is there a way to override hello() to do something else?

Currently, when I try overriding it,

```
namespace a.b.c {
    export function hello() {console.log('hi')}
}
```

I'm getting error message when I try something like this:

> error TS2384: Overload signatures must all be ambient or non-ambient.

Assume that I can't change the .d.ts.

It doesn't need to be pretty, but in the end, I need to be able to call

```
a.b.c.hello();
```

and get the value from the new function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you said it doesn't have to be pretty.... does this work for you:

```
namespace a.b.c {
    export function hello() {
        const elem = document.createElement("p");
        elem.innerText = "Hello";
        document.body.append(elem);
    }
}

a.b.c["hello"] = () => {
    const elem = document.createElement("p");
    elem.innerText = "HI!";
    document.body.append(elem);
}

a.b.c.hello();
```